# Setting Cassandra password in reference.conf using Scala

Tags: scala

How can an attribute be set programmatically in a `reference.conf` file?

For example, I am using something like this in Spring to set the attributes of the keystore:

```
System.setProperty("server.ssl.keyStore", "keystore.jks")
System.setProperty("server.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password123")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way, you can override configuration from the reference conf file using system properties, they have the highest precedence order as described here:
https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior

Please be aware you need to do it before the config is loaded by the class that uses it (via ConfigFactory.load()) and if any other class has already used ConfigFactory, then a call to ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches() will also be required, otherwise the cached value will be used.